# [Excel]Added a sheet from a different workbook, still getting "Update Values" Dialogue Box

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet, copying

I copied over a worksheet from 1 workbook to a more comprehensive one. In this copied worksheet, I've tried to have some cells automatically calculate based on the other worksheets. For instance Cell A1=CustomerName, where CustomerName is a named cell elsewhere in the workbook.

However, typing =CustomerName into the cell open up a dialogue box saying "update Values" and asks me to select a file. I'd rather it just automatically took the value currently in the workbook, but don't know why it's trying to make me select a file. I checked the connections, and there is nothing listed. Thanks

Comment: check under data->edit links, if there's any linked excels, maybe the sheet you copied has links to other sheets

Answer (score 0):

Go to the 'File' Ribbon - on the right there should be an option 'Edit Links to Files'. Here you can break the connection to your old workbook.

Comment: I selected the item and hit "Break Links", but this done not appear to do anything, and the item is still on the list. No error message is given.

Comment: If you use Office 2013 or newer version you can also try: File Ribbon --> Inspect Documents. This will show all conncetions (not just links but also Queries to other sources) and provides normally the option to remove those connections.